# How to set auto-forward message on existing queue or subscription in azure service bus?

Tags: azure, azureservicebus

The following article says that auto-forward can be enabled on a queue or a subscription:

```
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-auto-forwarding
```

The shown code uses either QueueDescription or SubscriptionDescription, which are used when creating a new queue or new subscription.

Since this appears to be a server level feature, I thought I could update an existing queue to configure auto-forwarding to another topic or queue. Naturally I went to azure service bus portal. But I did not find a way to set this in the portal.

Does this mean:

1. Is this feature enabled only when I create a queue or subscription
   through code?
2. Or Is there any other way to do this on existing queue or subscription?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can update [Queue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.updatequeueasync?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_UpdateQueueAsync_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_)/[Subscription](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.servicebus.namespacemanager.updatesubscriptionasync?view=azureservicebus-4.0.0#Microsoft_ServiceBus_NamespaceManager_UpdateQueueAsync_Microsoft_ServiceBus_Messaging_QueueDescription_) Description and set the forwarding via code or use a tool for that. The portal doesn't support it, but a tool such as [Service Bus Explorer](https://github.com/paolosalvatori/ServiceBusExplorer/releases) (or similar) does.

Answer (score 2):

The Azure CLI supports this now, e.g.

```sh
az servicebus queue update -g my-rg --namespace-name my-namespace --name queue1 --forward-to queue2
```

Docs: [Queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/queue?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-queue-update), [Subscriptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/servicebus/topic/subscription?view=azure-cli-latest#az-servicebus-topic-subscription-update)